# How to add database columns from table to combobox

Tags: c#, database, combobox

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            con.Open();
            DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("TABLES").AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("TABLE_TYPE") == "TABLE").CopyToDataTable(); 
            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
                comboBoxTabel.Items.Add(r["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
            con.Close();
    }
    private void comboBoxTabel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //con.Open();
        //DataTable dt = con.GetSchema("COLUMNS");
        //foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
           //comboBoxKolom.Items.Add(r.Field<string>("COLUMN_NAME"));
    }
```

Can someone help me out please? When the program loads it shows all the tables from the database in the first combobox (comboBoxTabel). What i want is when you click on a table, that the columns of that table appear in the 2nd combobox (comboBoxKolom).